# cookies issue in python with requests module

Tags: python, api, python-requests, session-cookies

i will try to summarize the issue i have.
I am using  the below script .. to retrieve some information from remote server

```
import requests
import urllib3
import time

ip_add = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
usr = "username"
pwd = "pwd@2016"

## to skip ssl warnings
urllib3.disable_warnings()

##1- is to add token

url = "https://" +ip_add + ":8443/cas/v1/tickets"
payload = 'username=' +usr + '&password='+ pwd
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response_token = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data = payload, verify=False)
response_token.raise_for_status()

if response_token.status_code == 201:
  print("Status  : ",response_token.status_code , "OK", " >>> Normal")
  tgt = response_token.headers['location']
  file = open(r'D:\tgt','w')
  print(tgt, file=file)
  file.close()
else:
  print("Status : ", response_token.status_code)
file = open(r'D:\tgt','r')
tgt = file.readline()
print(tgt)



print("Moving to step 2 .. \n")
time.sleep(1)
##---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


##2- is to make service ticket
url = tgt


payload = 'service=https%3A//'+ip_add+ '%3A8443/oms1350'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
tkt = print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
file = open(r'D:\tkt', 'w')
print(response.text, file=file)
file.close()

if response.status_code == 200:
  print("Status  : ",response.status_code , "OK", " >>> Normal")

else:
  print("Status : ", response.status_code)
file = open(r'D:\tkt','r')
tkt = file.readline()

print("Moving to step 3 .. \n")
time.sleep(1)

##-------------------------------------------------------------------


##3- is to make login session
url = "https://" + ip_add + ":8443/oms1350/data/plat/session/login"
payload = 'user=' + usr + '&password=' + pwd + '&presentation=' + ip_add + '&ticket=' + tkt


headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False,)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.cookies)
```

## #

for the 1st and 2nd sections, i receive the correct response ( 201 and 200 ).

for the 3rd part which is :

```
##3- is to make login session
url = "https://" + ip_add + ":8443/oms1350/data/plat/session/login"
payload = 'user=' + usr + '&password=' + pwd + '&presentation=' + ip_add + '&ticket=' + tkt

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False,)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.cookies)
```

i do not receive the needed output. the output is :

```
 Status : 401
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=2B145F3A5A9B1E0DD2BC642FD6686EBC for 135.183.142.80/oms1350>]>
```

i know it is cookies issue, because when i copy the cookies from postman and paste it in headers like this :

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=3897E226E810E313ED9D456921E16280D5'
}
```

it work normally, and receive status code 200.

so how can i generate a valid cookies to login ?
NOTE : each time i run response.post i receive new cookies.

UPDATE :
i have modified the 3rd section to this :

```
##3- is to make login session
url ="https://" + ip_add + ":8443/oms1350/data/common/login"
payload = 'user=' + usr + '&password=' + pwd + '&presentation=' + ip_add + '&ticket=' + tkt

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response.cookies)
print(response.status_code)
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,verify=False,data= payload, cookies=response.cookies)
print(response.cookies)
print(response.status_code)
```

and This is the output :

```
Moving to step 3 .. 
--------------------------
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=A86F4BEEE2BB844E0A0CF8E6A00579654FB9 for xx.xx.xx.xx/oms1350>]>
401
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
401
```

Comment: The cookie is generated on the server side - you need to make a GET request to the login page to capture that cookie, before making the POST request.

Comment: i have tried that but no luck.

response1 = requests.get(url,headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False)
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False,cookies=response1.cookies)

Comment: Your comment in response is different to the modified second method you posted that worked.  Are you sure the `response1.cookies` in fact has the cookies?  Also you supplied `data=payload` with the `requests.get` which differ to the data-free GET request that browsers typically will send, this may also be a source of interference. Please print out the relevant values and update your question.

Comment: i have updated the question with the output.